# insert if not exist, update if exist and a condition is true

Tags: mysql

I have a table that contains `id`(primary key), `user_id` and `name`. I want to insert a new record if the `user_id` is different than the existing `user_id`s, and also if the `user_id` is the same but the `name` of this `user_id` is changed, the `name` should be updated. How to do that. I have done this, but it does not update for the same `user_id` with a different `name`.

```
CREATE TABLE test 
    (
     id int auto_increment primary key, 
     user_id int,
     name varchar(60)
    );


INSERT INTO test (user_id,name)
VALUES('01','user1');
INSERT INTO test (user_id,name)
VALUES('02','user2');
INSERT INTO test (user_id,name)
VALUES('03','user3');




insert into test (user_id, name) values('01', 'new_user') on duplicate key update name=values(name);
```

Here is the `sqlfiddle`: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/aa18e/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare `user_id` as `UNIQUE`, like:

```
CREATE TABLE test 
    (
     id int auto_increment, 
     user_id int,
     name varchar(60),
     primary key(id),
     unique key(user_id)
    );
```

Updated fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6a5d1/1

Comment: Is there a way without making user_id as unique, or if i make two columns unique together instead only user_id, your suggestion will work?

Comment: @CoKoder you said you wanted to insert a record if the `user_id` does not exist, and update if the `user_id` exists. The only way to do that with an `insert ... on duplicate key` statement is declaring `user_id` as unique.

Comment: @Mihai what do you mean?